# Implicit json Writes and Reads for Java8 ZonedDateTime in Play 2.3.x?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, java-time

The new Play 2.4 has added out of the box support for json `Writes` and `Reads` for the new Java 8 time classes, but Play 2.3.x is still stuck with the Joda time json support only. Is there a way to get the Java 8 time json support on the 2.3.x? How the custom `Reads` and `Writes` for `ZonedDateTime` would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the play 2.4 `Writes` and `Reads` code directly from their source code, or read it and adapt your own:

Writes:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/702e89841fc54f5603a0d981c3488ed9883561fe/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Writes.scala

Reads:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/cde65d987b6cf3c307dfab8269b87a65c5e84575/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala

If you copy the files wholesale and remove the contravariant functor reads/writes, they will have no external dependencies beyond Java8 & Scala.

I'm obviously not advocating this kind of copy & paste in general, but I'd don't see that it would do any harm here, as it's just a stop-gap until your project migrates to play 2.4, at which point they can be deleted.

Comment: This seems to work, but there's one gotcha: if you copy those files verbatim, you'll face `NoSuchMethodException` when trying to use anything from them, because some parts of those are duplicated in the Play 2.3.x. So one needs to carefully extract the code related to `ZonedDateTime`, and put it in a different package.